# How to know if data POSTed by client app to an API are original/not altered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, microservices

I am new to web development and I have a question which might sound dumb.

**The question:**

Let's say we have a **microservices** architecture, where the microservices live in the back end and in the front end there is a client app that collects data from the microservices by consuming their APIs and then builds some HTML, populates it with that data and serves it to the user.

**How can I know that the data that the user POSTs back to my client app, and eventually to my microservices, isn't "altered" by the user** in a way to exploit our business model? By the term "altered" it doesn't mean necessary malicious data to harm our system, like an SQL injection input, or invalid data, like unaccepted values, but valid data that are not in their original values, like a "mistake" happened.

**Example:**

Imagine we have an "e-commerce" website based on microservices, where there is a "Catalog" microservice, which holds all the products of our business along with their information (price, stock, etc) and a "Basket" microservice which holds the Basket for each user of our website. We also have an MVC client app that communicates with these microservices by internally consuming the APIs provided by them.

In the Catalog API there is a GetAllProducts endpoint, that GETs all the products of our Catalog to the caller. The client app calls that endpoint on Catalog API, gets the data, populates the HTML and serves it to the user.

In the Basket API there is an AddProductToBasket endpoit, that POSTs a ProductDTO object which the microservice will validate and then store to the user's Basket. The ProductDTO object contains information like ProductId, ProductName, UnitPrice, Units, etc.

A scenario like the one I tried to describe above is when the user, after GETing all the Catalog products through the client app, he creates an "altered" ProductDTO and POSTs it back to AddProductToBasket endpoint (again through the client app). The "altered" ProductDTO will look like this:

```
"ProductDTO":{
                "ProductId":"1234",
                "ProductName":"PlayStation 5",
                "UnitPrice":5,
                "Units":1
             }
```

While it should have looked like this, based on the data the Catalog API returned:

```
"ProductDTO":{
                "ProductId":"1234",
                "ProductName":"PlayStation 5",
                "UnitPrice":500,
                "Units":1
             }
```

As you can see, the user is trying to exploit our business model by adding a product to his Basket with a lower price than the original. But the same alteration in POSTed data could happen with any of the ProductDTO properties.

My question is, how can I know, when I receive the ProductDTO at the Basket microserice, that the Price field has an incorrect value? Note that the Basket microservice doesn't store the information of the products, as this is out of the Basket's context. Products information are stored in Catalog microservice.

**A probable solution:**

A solution I can think of is to change the POSTed ProductDTOs to look like this:

```
"ProductDTO":{
                "ProductId":"1234",
                "Units":1
             }
```

The idea is that now the ProductDTO object will instead be POSTed to the Catalog API endpoint (let's say to a RequestToAddProductToBasket endpoint) and the Catalog will only receive the ProductId and the desired Units from the user. It will then perform some business-rules level validation (e.g. there is available Stock for the desired Units) and then it will send to the Basket a new ProductDTO object, populated with all the necessary values, like ProductName, Price, Units, etc, though a back-end communication channel (like an Event Bus).
Basket, in turn, will receive the new ProductDTO and will use the data from it to add the Product to the user's Basket. This way it's "guaranteed" that the newly added Product has original data.

-

I just have a feeling that my way of thinking misses something obvious and I am over-complexing the solution. It's also probable that I have not understand how the client apps work and that it isn't that easy to POST an "altered" object to an API through the client app.

Please, let me know if the "problem" that I'm seeing here is real or not and if my proposed solution is a viable one or if there is a better workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you send the price of that item in a request? You can get that value from a database table and it would just calculate the amount of stuff the user added and then return a total value

Comment: @cristi_nmr You mean to get that Product info, inside my client app's controller, with a request to Catalog API and then post that data to the Basket API?

Comment: In my opinion the request should not contain ANY data that, if modified, can do bad things like you mentioned in your question (buy a PS 5 for 5 UnitPrice). You should just send the ProductID and Units, then, in the backend, calculate the total price by taking the price of the product from the database (which cannot be altered by users) and multiply it with the Units, then retrieve the total price. I don't really use ASP.NET, but idea should be possible on all frameworks.

Comment: @cristi_nmr I aggree with your approach. The problem is that if I send the request to Basket microservice, the Product's info are not present there to load them by the ProductId. In fact, product info are stored in Catalog microservice. So, for now, I will stick with the solution I am proposing above, where I send the ProductId to Catalog microservice, then the Catalog will load the Product's info and send them through the event bus to the Basket microservice in order for the Product with the "correct" data to be added to user's Basket. Anyway, thank you for your time to reply to my question.